# Jenkins pipeline job: Set sleep time from a string parameter?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to Jenkins Pipeline jobs, and I'm facing an issue I cannot solve.

I have a stage with a hardcoded `sleep` seconds value:

```
stage ("wait_prior_starting_smoke_testing") {
  echo 'Waiting 5 minutes for deployment to complete prior starting smoke testing'
  sleep 300 // seconds
}
```

But I would like to provide the time argument via a job (string) parameter `SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECONDS`. But whatever I have tried, I am not able to get it to work.

How do you convert a string parameter to the `int` time argument?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Finally I did found a way to get this work:

```
stage ("wait_prior_starting_smoke_testing") {
    def time = params.SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECONDS
    echo "Waiting ${SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECONDS} seconds for deployment to complete prior starting smoke testing"
    sleep time.toInteger() // seconds
}
```

Answer (score 81):

*small improve for this page:*

You also can use `sleep(time:3,unit:"SECONDS")` if you are interested in specifying time unit of your sleep

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#sleep-sleep

Comment: Don't omit `time:` and `unit:` else Jenkins will error with `Arguments to "sleep" must be explicitly named`

Answer (score 9):

Try this. It work for me.

```
stage ("wait_for_testing")
{
   sh 'sleep 300'
}
```

With "sh" you start virtual terminal with shell. If you need write other command in one terminal, write ; after command.
For example:

```
sh 'pwd; sleep 300; echo "Hello World"'
```

Comment: The dedicated Jenkins `sleep()` function should be more portable.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to inject sleep during the pipeline execution. The below pipeline is working fine in the Jenkins version 2.319.2.

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage('Sleep') {
        steps {
            script {
                print('I am sleeping for a while')
                sleep(30)    
            }
            
        }
    }
     stage('Please let me Sleep 30 seconds more') {
        steps {
            echo 'Please let me Sleep 30 seconds more'
            sleep(time:30, unit: "SECONDS")
        }
    }
    stage('After Sleep') {
        steps {
            echo 'Already woke up!'
        }
    }
}
}
```