# Make Jenkins build job execute for longer time. On purpose. For testing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have some dummy Jenkins build job "JOB1", which is getting triggered from Pipeline (Jenkinsfile).

Now, to test behavior of my pipeline in case of JOB1's extremely long duration, I need a way, how I can make "JOB1" continue execution longer.

Currently, my JOB1 is getting triggered, then it checks something out, then it finishes with SUCCESS. Do you have an idea, what I can do to make this simple dummy JOB1 continue longer? Preferrable would be an idea with predictable/configurable duration.

I could imagine some time delay after triggering and before the end. But how could this idea be implemented?

Comment: Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912821/jenkins-pipeline-job-set-sleep-time-from-a-string-parameter) contain the answer to your question?

Comment: @RNoB  Thank you, but it does not. That question is about how to make pipeline wait for something. My question is about how to make a triggered job continue longer.

Comment: So you have a pipeline from where you are calling a job and you want to simulate a long running job? Or do you have a pipeline that triggers another jenkins (not a pipeline) job?

Comment: @RNoB:  I have a pipeline from where I am calling a job and I want to increase duration of the called job.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
 sh "sleep 120"
```

that should run a process on the agent that does nothing and takes 2 minutes to complete. 
If you use `sleep 120` (without the `sh` command) you block the thread in the master instead.

Comment: Muchas gracias!